# Oracle: Can't pull from data from joined table: Single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: database, oracle, subquery

I have an `orders` table with the following fields.

order_id, 
order_status_id, 
ordered_date

And I have a `shipments` table with the following fields.
(When I update `order_status_id` to 3 in `orders` table, I do have to insert `order_id and shipped_at` to `shipments` table.)

shipment_id, 
order_id, 
shipped_at

I want to select all from orders where order_status_id is 3. I also together want to get `shipped_at` from shipments table.

My try is like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    o.*, 
    s.shipped_at,
        FROM orders o
            JOIN shipments s ON s.order_id = o.order_id
        WHERE o.order_status_id = 3;
```

The above gives me empty results but I do have data.

```sql
SELECT 
    s.*, 
    o.*, 
    FROM shipments s
        JOIN orders o ON o.order_id = s.order_id
    WHERE s.order_id = (SELECT o.order_id FROM orders o WHERE o.order_status_id = 3);
```

This gives me `Single-row subquery returns more than one row` error.

Please help.

Comment: some sample data and perhaps some sample table would be helpful in this case . Your first query looks fine to me. I would remove the `o.order_status_id = 3;`  and see if you get data. Than work backwards from there.

Comment: Without that condition, I'm getting all orders. I just need order_status_id = 3 data.

Comment: are there any spaces in that colum? Again im guessing without any sample data.  but if you are trying to filter on `3` and there are spaces like in that field than you would end up with nothing on result. Perhaps try `trim` on `o.order_status_id` something like `TRIM(o.order_status_id)=3` or you can try to debug with a `like` statement such as `o.order_status_id like  %3%;`

Comment: I think data in shipment table do not exists. (Wild guess). Try to use `left join` instead of `join` in your first query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that your subquery `(select o.order_id...)` returns more than one row, but `=` requires exactly 1 row. If you want to accept multiple results, use `in` instead. You also need to correlate your subquery with the main query.

```
SELECT 
    s.*, 
    o.*, 
    FROM shipments s
        JOIN orders o ON o.order_id = s.order_id
    WHERE s.order_id in (SELECT o.order_id FROM orders o WHERE o.order_status_id = 3 and o.order_id = s.order_id);
```

In this case, you've already joined `orders`, so you don't need the subquery. You can troubleshoot why you're missing data with a full outer join.

```
SELECT 
    s.*, 
    o.*, 
    FROM shipments s
    FULL OUTER JOIN orders o ON o.order_id = s.order_id
    WHERE o.order_status_id = 3;
```